# Make SQL Server database read only except for one stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, sqlconnection

I have a stored procedure which migrate data from this database to another. To exclude any error, I want to make the database read only for every transaction except mine. I use SqlConnection and SqlCommand to run the script. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Grant your login the appropriate permissions, but deny them to all other logins. Be aware that members of the sysadmin role cannot be denied permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately our every process runs on behalf of sysadmin. I know it is not a good solution, but that is we have.

Comment: Can you put the database in Single-User mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the database to `Single-user Mode`.  When you put it in Single-user mode, then you have the only connection available. As long as you don't relinquish your connection, no one else can connect.

Be warned, this will close all existing connections by other users.  But it will prevent other connections from being made.

More information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx

Comment: It sounds good. But is there a way to exclude other connections to grab the database before mine?

Comment: @KissLászló I'm not sure that I understand your question.  If you put it in Single-user mode, then you have the only connection available.  As long as you don't relinquish your connection, no one else can connect.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that. Thank you!

Comment: @KissLászló I added that to the answer